# Python regular expression to remove caption

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text crawled from a webpage:

> A female believed to be around 25 years old, she was captured in the
>   wild in Malaysian Borneo in 2011 and lived the rest of her life at the
>   Tabin Wildlife Reserve in Sabah, a fenced-in facility managed by BORA.
>   [caption id="attachment_194682" align="aligncenter" width="768"] Rhino
>   being cared for at the Borneo rhino sanctuary. Photo courtesy of Sabah
>   Wildlife Department.[/caption] Overall, between 55 and 100 of the
>   Critically Endangered species are believed to remain

You can see that there is text between squared brackets of caption. Basically, I want to remove everything between squared brackets, and the sentence

> Rhino being cared for at the Borneo rhino sanctuary. Photo courtesy of
>   Sabah Wildlife Department

because it is the caption for an image. So the result should be:

> A female believed to be around 25 years old, she was captured in the
>   wild in Malaysian Borneo in 2011 and lived the rest of her life at the
>   Tabin Wildlife Reserve in Sabah, a fenced-in facility managed by BORA.
>   Overall, between 55 and 100 of the Critically Endangered species are
>   believed to remain ...

How can I do it?

Comment: This is not a regex writing service. What effort have you made to solve this yourself?

Comment: Oh, I think it is. I've tried several solutions on this site with python regex but not successful.

Comment: I think it's not, and the downvotes you're receiving are indicating that I'm correct. The fact you got someone to write one for you does not change the fact that this is not a code writing service, and if you continue trying to treat it as one it's not going to go well for you.

Comment: @KenWhite Oh, sorry, I thought you meant the tag is wrong. In fact, I've tried some solutions with regex, and I didn't understand well python regular expression, that's why I'm asking for help here.

Comment: And that's why I'm asking you to show what you've already tried as part of your question. It shows you made an effort. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/62576) for a discussion of *zero-effort questions* (which includes *please write my code for me* posts) and why they're not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the python `re` module to fetch data between caption like so:

```
import re
text = """
A female believed to be around 25 years old, she was captured in the wild in Malaysian Borneo in 2011 and lived the rest of her life at the Tabin Wildlife Reserve in Sabah, a fenced-in facility managed by BORA. [caption id="attachment_194682" align="aligncenter" width="768"] Rhino being cared for at the Borneo rhino sanctuary. Photo courtesy of Sabah Wildlife Department.[/caption] Overall, between 55 and 100 of the Critically Endangered species are believed to remain
"""

pattern = r'\[caption.*\](.*)\[/caption\]'
items = re.search(pattern, text)
print text.replace(items.group(0), '')

#  A female believed to be around 25 years old, she was captured in the wild in Malaysian Borneo in 2011 and lived the rest of her life at the Tabin Wildlife Reserve in Sabah, a fenced-in facility managed by BORA.  Overall, between 55 and 100 of the Critically Endangered species are believed to remain
```

Comment: Please have a look at my edited question. I'd like to get the text outside [caption] area.

Comment: @lenhhoxung edited my answer

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot.